# Bash script not outputting nohup.out + Jenkins

Tags: bash, jenkins, nohup

I have a bash script that I am calling from a build step in Jenkins. Within this bash script is a nohup command for calling a different script in the background, such as:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup otherScript.sh &
```

After the build step completes I go to the path where the nohup.out should have been created, but there is nothing there. Any ideas on what is going on?

Comment: By using Jenkins for running a command in the background you are defeating its purpose, which is to monitor your scripts as they run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should make sure that the output goes into your build's workspace.  This will avoid permission problems with other directories.

```
nohup otherScript.sh > $WORKSPACE/scriptOutput.txt 2>&1 &
```

Comment: Is the final `&` not unwanted? It makes the script continue with succes even on an error case... ?

Comment: Maybe, but the original question has the & so I included it in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from `man nohup`:

> If  standard input is a terminal, redirect it from /dev/null. If standard output is a terminal, append output to `nohup.out` if possible, `$HOME/nohup.out` otherwise. If standard error is a terminal, redirect it to standard output. To save output to FILE, use `nohup  COMMAND > FILE`.

Running the command from Jenkins probably means that `STDOUT` is not a terminal, thus `nohup.out` is not created. As [gareth_bowles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16902950/1630171) already suggested, you should redirect the output to a file with a defined path:

```
nohup script.sh >/path/to/output.log 2>&1 &
```